# Getting notification when someone detach EBS Volumes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I want to get notifications when someone detaches their EBS Volume.
So can anyone help me out with any solutions?

Comment: Looks like there are EventBridge notifications for Attaching volumes, but not Detaching volumes: [EventBridge for Amazon EBS - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-cloud-watch-events.html)

Comment: You have to do it through AWS Config and/or CloudTrial.